# Google map V2 not initializing after granting permission on pop up dialog

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-api-2

I have implemented google maps and google places for my application. I have realized that google maps does not initialize properly when I install the application the first time i.e when the used allows google maps permission via the permission pop up dialog, the google maps window defaults to its original map without showing my current location and also places autocomplete field does not work (meaning google maps did not initialize). However, when i run the app the second and third time it works perfectly.

Below is my Code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback,
        LocationListener {
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean executeOnStart = false;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_INDIA = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-0, 0), new LatLng(0, 0));
    public GoogleMap mMap;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    private String mapAddress = null;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button checkAvailability;
    private StringBuilder sb = null;
    private EditText mAutocompleteView;
    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    private LatLng latLng;
    private Marker marker;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter mAutoCompleteAdapter;
    PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item;
    String featureName, locality, countryName;
    String placeId;
    ImageView delete;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private boolean allowEditTextChangeListener = true; 
    private LatLng pos;
    static boolean invalidLocation = false;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        mAutocompleteView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_places);

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

        Log.d("allowEditTextChange1",allowEditTextChangeListener + "");
        checkAvailability = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_availability);
        checkAvailability.setTypeface(Display.displayTypeface(getApplicationContext(), 1));


        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        delete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cross);

        mAutoCompleteAdapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.searchview_adapter,
                mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_INDIA, null);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAutoCompleteAdapter);
        // mRecyclerView.setLayoutFrozen(true);
        delete.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (allowEditTextChangeListener) {
            Log.d("allowEditTextChangz1",allowEditTextChangeListener + "");
            mAutocompleteView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                          int count) {
                    Log.d("allowEditTextChangz1","jo");
                    if (!s.toString().equals("") && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                        mAutoCompleteAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                    } else if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                     //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e(Constants.PlacesTag, Constants.API_NOT_CONNECTED);
                    }

                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            });
        }
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        item = mAutoCompleteAdapter.getItem(position);
                        placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                                .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
                        placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                                if (places.getCount() == 1) {
                                    mAutoCompleteAdapter.clear();
                                    mAutocompleteView.setText("");
                                    String country = "";

                                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                            .target(places.get(0).getLatLng())      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                                            .zoom(12)                   // Sets the zoom
                                            .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                                            .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                                            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

                                    marker.remove(); // remove any marker from maponclick or maponlonclick
                                    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(places.get(0).getLatLng())
                                            .title("My Location"));
                                    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                            }
                        });
                        Log.i("TAG", "Clicked: " + item.description);
                        Log.i("TAG", "Called getPlaceById to get Place details for " + item.placeId);
                    }
                })
        );

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maps_close);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("close", "close");
                if (mAutoCompleteAdapter.getItemCount() != 0){
                    mAutoCompleteAdapter.clear();
                }
                mAutocompleteView.setText("");
            }
        });

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;

        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        final Double lat = location.getLatitude();
        final Double lng = location.getLongitude();
        Log.d("LATLANGz", lat + "|" + lng);
        latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Positionn");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==delete){
            mAutocompleteView.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()){
            Log.v("Google API","Connecting");
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            Log.v("Google API","Dis-Connecting");
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        if (isNetworkAvailable() == true){
            if (isLocationEnabled(getApplicationContext())){
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    checkLocationPermission();
                }
                // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            } else{
                showLocationDialog();
            }
        } else {
            showInternetDialog();
        }

    }

    public void showInternetDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Please turn on mobile network or Wi-Fi in Settings.")
                .setTitle("WIFI Disabled")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Settings",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                MapsActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        }
                );
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    // check internet connectivity
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }

    public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
        int locationMode = 0;
        String locationProviders;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            try {
                locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

            } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;

        }else{
            locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
        }
    }

    public void showLocationDialog(){
        executeOnStart = true;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.gps_not_found_message)
                .setTitle(R.string.gps_not_found_title)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Settings",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dg, int id) {
                                MapsActivity.this.finish();

                            }
                        }
                );
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For current location: this is because in `onMapReady()` your do:

```
buildGoogleApiClient();
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

if permissions already granted, and only:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}
```

in `onRequestPermissionsResult()`. Just add `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` to `onRequestPermissionsResult()` like that:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

For autocomplete: in `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` you call `buildGoogleApiClient();` and create `mAutoCompleteAdapter` before getting permission (on first app launch):

```
...
buildGoogleApiClient();
delete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cross);

mAutoCompleteAdapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.searchview_adapter, mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_INDIA, null);
....
```

so, you should also call `mAutoCompleteAdapter = new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(...)` in  `onRequestPermissionsResult()`.

Comment: So, you can accept answer :) (To do this you should click the checkmark under question rate, on the left right below the vote arrows ant it's should become green.)

Comment: @G.Joe Thanx! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not loading it properly during 
`onRequestPermissionsResult` method .
try some tricks ask permission request during splash page activity.

Comment: This is a good idea, so I should be asking all my application permissions on splash screen activity?

Comment: yes, during the first time your app splash screen is running

Comment: I think this is the best option since if you call your permissions in your maps activity you will need to execute two times the things inside onMapready, since if its the first time the app is runing it will go to onMapReady, then ask the permissions from there and in your onRequestPermissionResults you will need to handle duplicated logic since you will need to trigger the things inside onMapReady twice, when you accept the permission and then just on onMapReady when you start again the app, doing this in splash screen prevents this, so you enter the app with all permissions granted.